# javafx how to set center position for text or label?

Tags: java, javafx

How to set centerX and centerY for `Text` or `Label` node in JavaFX?

AFAIK, there is no specific property (or method) for center position, but there are `setLayoutX, setLayoutY` methods + `relocate`, which I can't understand how they work.

Comment: If you are using Scene Builder you can specify this in node section of layout containing label

Comment: You need to set the alignment in your parent and not in the node itself.

Answer (score 5):

You have to tell to your parent layout how to display children. Not children how to display themself.

For example if your button is inside an Hbox just do :

```
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)
```

You should read [Working with layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm) for a better understanding

Comment: What if you don't use a grid layout, but you need to use absolute positions, and want the text to be centered at coordinates (x,y) (yes, text may overlap)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center text in `Pane` container based on mouse coordinate, try this one

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CenterTextWithCoordinateDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        pane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circle.setRadius(10);
            circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
            circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
            pane.getChildren().add(circle);

            Text text = new Text();
            text.setText("This is a long text");
            text.setX(event.getX());
            text.setY(event.getY());
            text.setX(text.getX() - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2);
            text.setY(text.getY() + text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 4);
            pane.getChildren().add(text);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Center Text With Coordinate Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]